# Why does Hexo blog show my image twice in post?

Tags: hexo

I am running a [**Hexo Blog**](http://hexo.io/) on my localhost, port #4000.

My Hexo blog software lives in a directory called `Mongoose`.
I ran the server by going into `Mongoose/blog` and typing `hexo server -d`

Here is what my file structure looks like:

[image]

When I point my browser to `localhost:4000` everything looks exactly in order, as it should be. However, when I then click on my blog post (entitled ***Hello World 5***).

I see the the screenshot below. As you can see, the image that is supposed to be embedded in my blog post is actually appearing twice. Why? And how can I fix it? In the image above, you can see the markdown that produced this.

[image]

Comment: Active discussion of this issue is going on here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hexo/jcLvY_NkM1w

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it is a bug for the `landscape` theme. I also reproduce that. `landscape` is perhaps default theme for hexo. Why don't you try other themes? There are lots of other beautiful themes out there. Refer to the following URL.

https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/wiki/themes

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Solution. There was a Hexo bug that has been fixed in newer versions: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hexo/jcLvY_NkM1w